# Is there any Todo and Notes list manager available on Ubuntu which can sync with android device using Syncthing?

Tags: android, notes

Is there any app combination available on Ubuntu and android so that it can use syncthing to sync with each other?

Like Carnet but it use Nextcloud. I found syncthing very low resource consuming, not sure about Nextcloud.

Comment: Purpose of using Syncthing was to disconnect from Google. I was thinking ,if is it is possible to sync notes on local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wish to move away from Google Keep have you considered Simplenote downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Center?

[image]